# Twitching Scrollbar in listview with dynamic height children

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scrollbar

Code example: https://gist.github.com/v1z4/4c231063b9e22eac5961fb0c437119fe

I have a list of dynamic elements with different height, and I need to have a scrollbar. I use iOS style widgets, so I have wrapped ListView in CupertinoScrollbar().

I test it in real device attached, because simulator does not have scrollbar.

The list works fine, but scrollbar is twitching, because the height of elements are different.

It works fine when I add fixed height to container in ListView element, but text is being cropped and looks bad. Is there a way to fix twitching?